# Executable downloaded from Cloudfront in IE11 (Windows 7) downloads without a file extension

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, internet-explorer-11, amazon-cloudfront

The long-short of it is an `.exe` downloaded from Cloudfront (using signed URLs) in IE11/Win7 downloads without an extension (`exe_file.exe -> exe_file`)

I **don't** think that it's the same issue as described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/93c4f545-66ed-4372-bc53-3dea51d5479e/how-do-i-stop-ie-11-from-renaming-downloads?forum=ieitprocurrentver) (among many, many other places) as the file is not renamed `exe_file_exe`, the extension is just dropped.

The file is being served from Cloudfront from S3 - and was uploaded via aws-cli

```
$ aws s3 cp exe_file.exe s3://cdn/exe_file.exe --content-type "application/x-msdownload"
```

as far as I'm aware the `content-type` argument isn't absolutely necessary as CF/S3/something, at some point, tries to do some intelligent MIME assigning (plus, before, when I was uploading without that arg, inspecting the download headers would show the correct MIME type).

Headers received when downloading the file

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-msdownload
Content-Length: 69538768
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 17:36:51 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 22:31:59 GMT
ETag: "c8fc68a920e198dca95e5549f8657bfb"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 335
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

This *only* happens in IE11 on Windows 7 - it works fine on IE11/Windows 10 (I say only but I have not tried on, for example, IE8 - you couldn't pay me enough money to put myself through that). And it does not happen with other downloads - `dmg_file.dmg` and `linux_file.zip` are both downloaded with the extension. Other browsers are also not impacted - they all download the file as-is in S3.

I have tried with and without AVs present - it does not make a difference.

Comment: Can you show us the headers sent and received ? Do other servers work ? Why did you set the content type the way you did ?

Comment: @Marged I've added the headers I receive when I download the file. Other servers? What do you mean - I'm downloading from Cloudfront/S3. I set the content type the way I did because that's how the cloudfront/S3 docs (and aws-cli docs) say you should.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185570/internet-explorer-removes-exe-extension-from-download-when-followed-by-url-para

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `content-disposition` correctly:

Forcing *SaveAs* using the HTTP header
In order to force the browser to show *SaveAs* dialog when clicking a hyperlink you have to include the following header in HTTP response of the file to be downloaded:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<file name.ext>"; filename*=utf-8''<file name.ext>
```

Note: Those user agents that do not support the RFC 5987 encoding ignore `filename*` when it occurs after *filename*.

Where  is the filename you want to appear in SaveAs dialog (like finances.xls or mortgage.pdf) - without `<` and `>` symbols.

You have to keep the following in mind:

1. The filename should be in US-ASCII charset and shouldn't contain special characters: `< > \ " / : | ? *` space.
2. The filename should not have any directory path information specified.
3. The filename should be enclosed in double quotes but most browsers will support file names without double quotes.

Ancient browsers also required the following (not needed nowadays, but for a fool proof solution might be worth doing):

4. Content-Type header should be before Content-Disposition.
5. Content-Type header should refer to an unknown MIME type (at least until the older browsers go away).

So, you should use `cp` with options:

1. `--content-type (string)` Specify an explicit content type for this operation. This value overrides any guessed mime types.
2. `--content-disposition (string)` Specifies presentational information for the object.
3. `--metadata-directive REPLACE` Specifies whether the metadata is copied from the source object or replaced with metadata provided when copying S3 objects.

Note that if you are using any of the following parameters: `--content-type`, `content-language`, `--content-encoding`, `--content-disposition`, `--cache-control`, or `--expires`, you will need to specify `--metadata-directive REPLACE` for non-multipart copies if you want the copied objects to have the specified metadata values.

try:

```
aws s3 cp exe_file.exe s3://cdn/exe_file.exe --content-type "application/x-msdownload" --content-disposition "attachment; filename=\"exe_file.exe\"; filename*=utf-8''exe_file.exe" --metadata-directive REPLACE
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I supplied my own `response-content-disposition` parameter to the Cloudfront Signer:

in Python, it looked like

```
from botocore.signers import CloudFrontSigner

def generate_presigned_url(filename, headers={}):
    cf_signer = CloudFrontSigner(CF_KEY_ID, rsa_signer)
    headers = '&'.join(["%s=%s" % (key, urllib.quote_plus(value)) for key, value in headers.iteritems()])

    return cf_signer.generate_presigned_url(
        'https://' + CF_DOMAIN + '/' + filename + ("" if len(headers) == 0 else "?%s" % (headers)),
        # ... other params
    )
```

called using

```
cloudfront.generate_presigned_url(file_name, {
    'response-content-disposition': 'attachment; filename="exe_file.exe"; filename*=utf-8\'\'exe_file.exe'
})
```